# ActiveXObject in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, activex

I want to use javascript to create a textfile, so I used :

This Line of code:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

It's working properly in IE6 but not in IE8.

Any suggested solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE8 internet setting is more secure, to it doesn't allow activex objects. If you have to run this, goto Tools->Internet Options-> Security->Custom Level->choose enable or prompt activex..

Comment: The problem remains because its enabled.

Comment: try Custom Level -> ActiveX controls and plug-ins -> Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting

Comment: This is only a local fix. Your web app will still throw this error on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help you. Close the IE. Right click on IE and Run as Administrator. Problem solved. I faced the same issue.