# Using Javascript to connect SQL Server database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, connection

I need to use Javascript to read some data from SQl Server 2008 Database.
So I wrote this:(html page code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Database Connect</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadDB(){
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

var connectionstring="Data Source=ИЛЬЯ-ПК;Initial Catalog=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SIGMA_Database.mdf;User ID=Илья;Password="";Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT Username FROM Users", connection);
rs.MoveFirst();
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.MoveNext();
}

rs.close();
connection.close();

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadDB()">
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, nothing happens!
What is wrong with it?There're some cyrillic alphabet symbols in connection string, can it be a source of problem?Or another thing is going wrong?

Comment: What browser are you running this in?  Can you view the javascript errors?

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Web server? Local file? mht?

Comment: I seriously hope your security will not allow curious onlookers from accessing this file, and that this is an "interior only" file.

Comment: I use Google Chrome;
Everything is local;
Security doesn't matter now, I know that javascript isn't the best way to connect to database;

Answer (score 2):

This is IE only code, and even in IE you have to explicitly allow such thing, see accepted answer here:
[ActiveXObject in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964531/ie8-activexobject-problem)

Comment: However I use Chrome and Firefox, how to connect to database using javascript if I have these browsers?

Comment: @Ilya you can use `window.openDatabase` just Google it, the first result is: http://creativepark.net/blog/entry/id/1191

Comment: Yes, it is really good!The only thing that I didn't understand is where the database must be situated?I should write a full path in first parametre of window.openDatabase()?

Comment: @Ilya you don't give the path, the database is internal to the browser. If you need to work with existing database you will have to use server side language like `PHP` or `ASP` using web server software like IIS or Apache.

Comment: Another option if the code is to run locally only, is write `.vbs` file and have the user execute it directly. In there, you can use plain `vbscript` code.

Comment: I know, but is it possible to work with existing via javascript?

Comment: @Ilya only JScript Windows Scripting, not via web page.

Answer (score 1):

Your `connectionstring` is not escaped properly, it should be:

```
var connectionstring="Data Source=ИЛЬЯ-ПК;Initial Catalog=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\SIGMA_Database.mdf;User ID=Илья;Password=\"\";Provider=SQLOLEDB";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
s.Open("SELECT Username FROM Users", connection);
rs.MoveFirst();
while(!rs.EOF)
{
   document.write(rs.Fields.Item(1));
   rs.MoveNext();
}

rs.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Edited rs.Fields

Comment: If all else fails have you tried running IE Developer Toolbar  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your codes is that you are accessing the SQL Server database using physical drive path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SIGMA_Database.mdf;

Connect to SQL Server using the following codes

var strconnectionstring = "Data Source=your_server_name;Initial Catalog=your_database_name;User ID=database_user_id;Password=database_password;Provider=SQLOLEDB";