# save result to txt file on company shared folder

Tags: javascript, activex

this is my problem i cant save my results to driver x that is company shared folder and i have permission to write  for some reason , but i can save on driver c.

the messege show

> Webpage error details
>
> Message: Automation server can't create object Line: 93 Char: 1 Code:
>   0 URI:
>   file:///X:/OmrilDocs/Omrix%20Public/All%20Omrix%20Public/Training/index.html

notic : i can use only javascript , no server side language is allowd :(

this is the code i use

```
alert(answerText);
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("X:\OmrilDocs\Omrix Public\All Omrix Public\Training\text.txt", true);
s.WriteLine(answerText);
s.Close();
```

im using ie8 on xp 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964531/ie8-activexobject-problem might be related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `\` with `\\`.
It should look like:-

```
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("X:\\OmrilDocs\\Omrix Public\\All Omrix Public\\Training\\text.txt", true);
```

While it is running, it gives a popup window which you need to allow to create the file.

Screenshot look like:-

[image]

Comment: i try this but still the same error Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Sun, 11 Mar 2012 09:40:03 UTC


Message: Automation server can't create object
Line: 93
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///X:/OmrilDocs/Omrix%20Public/All%20Omrix%20Public/Training/index.html

can i save the file on driver c and then copy it to x driver ?

Answer (score 0):

Eventhought you've loaded index.html from server, the code is executed in the work station.

You've written the path literally in your function. However, FSO tries to find the target from the work station only, and it is not capable to follow a path associated to some drive letter. (In other work stations that same path might be associated to a different letter.)

So, you need to to use the real name (or IP) of that server:

`fso.CreateTextFile("//YOUR_SERVER_NAME/OmrilDocs...`

Also the saving folder have to exist. When using `true`-argument in `CreateTextFile` only a new file is created to the provided path, new folders are not. Hence if there is a misstypo in the pathname, function will fail.