# Error: "Activation Server cant create object" in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript for validating a browse field. As `files[0]` is not supported in IE, I used another code for IE.

```
         var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
         var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
         var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
         var size = thefile.size;
```

I have enabled ActiveX in browser but still I'm getting the error as "Activation Server cant create object"

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 ActiveXObject problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964531/ie8-activexobject-problem)

Answer (score 0):

It means the ActiveX security settings are set too high and do not allow the code to run. Add your page to trusted sites or change the browser's security zone settings the page is in.

Comment: @epascarello..is there any other way. ! coz we can't force the user to do these much things for accessing the site.So it would be great if there is any other alternative for this.

Comment: Any other way is to use some solution that does not have ActiveX. Aka Flash/Silverlight/Applets.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Internet Options -> choose the Security tab

Click the Custom Level button and enable the following settings:

- Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins
- Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe.